# Return the largest value of a given element of tuple keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dict with tuples as keys, and I want to obtain the largest value available, say for the second element of the tuple keys currently in the dictionary. For example, given:

```
my_dict = {('a', 1):value_1, ('b', 1):value_2, ('a', 2):value_3, ('c', 3):value_4, ('b', 2):value_5}
```

so the largest value for the second elements of the keys is 3.

What is the fastest way to derive this value?

Comment: Do you mean you want the dictionary value associated with the key whose second element is largest, or you want the second element of the key tuple itself?  That is, in your example, do you want 3 or do you want `value_4`?

Comment: @BrenBarn, I want the second element of the key tuple itself, so in my example, I want 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either:

```
largest_key = max(my_dict, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Or:

```
from operator import itemgetter
largest_key = max(my_dict, key=itemgetter(1))
```

According to DSM, iterating over a `dict` directly is faster than retrieving and iterating over `keys()` or `viewkeys()`.

What I think Ms. Zverina is talking about is converting your data structure from a `dict` with `tuple` keys to something like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'a': {
            1: value_1,
            2: value_3
         }
    'b': {
            1: value_2,
            2: value_5
         }
    'c': {
            3: value_4
         }
}
```

That way, if you wanted find the max of all values with `a`, you could simply do:

```
largest_key = max(d['a'])
```

At no extra cost. (Your data is already divided into subsets, so you don't have to waste computation on building subsets each time you do a search).

**EDIT**

To restrict your search to a given subset, do something like this:

```
>>> subset = 'a'
>>> largest_key_within_subset = max((i for i in my_dict if i[0] == subset), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Where `(i for i in my_dict if i[0] == subset)` is a generator that returns only keys that are in the given subset.

Comment: It looks like iterating over `my_dict` itself is faster than `my_dict.viewkeys()` which is itself faster than `my_dict.keys()`, or so says my 2.7.2 timeit result.

Comment: @JoelCornett, what if the first element of the key is given, say `a` in my example above, is there anything we can do to speed things up by restricting the search to a subset of keys?

Comment: @MLister: Searching a smaller subset would definitely be faster, but you have to take into account the cost of constructing the smaller subset on demand.

Comment: @MLister know first element doesn't help in your structure as looking for 'a' (a string) is more expensive then looking for biggest integer. It could help if you stored your items in a dictionary of lists, indexed by the first value in the tuple.

Comment: @JoelCornett, so how can we construct this smaller subset of keys efficiently? I cannot quite see how `max` function would work for us in this case...

Comment: @MariaZverina, thanks for the suggestion. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the 'dictionary of lists' part? Are you suggesting that instead of using tuples as keys, I should use lists as keys? And what do you mean by building an index of a dictionary?

Comment: @MLister: You can't use lists as keys (and you shouldn't) because they are mutable objects and their hash values could change.

Comment: @JoelCornett, thanks for the clarification. so basically we need to deconstruct the tuple keys and use a nested dictionary instead?

Comment: @MLister: It depends. If you plan on doing these kinds of restricted searches often, than I would say yes. If not, I would consider whether keeping the data in this form makes other common operations on the data more difficult.

Comment: @MLister +JoelCornett  Thank you - that's exactly what I was thinking off :)

Comment: @JoelCornett, actually, i would rather keep the tuple key construction . So what would be the fastest way to get the key with the largest value for the second element of the tuple, **among those whose first element is a given value (say `a`)**. So I am not searching for any keys, but only among the ones with first element as `a`.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for largest value i.e. 3 use this:

```
print max(my_dict.keys(), key = lambda x: x[1])[1]
```

If you are looking for largest value from the dict, use this:

```
my_dict = {('a', 1):'value_1', ('b', 1):'value_2', ('a', 2):'value_3', ('c', 3):'value_4', ('b', 2):'value_5'}

largest = max(my_dict.keys(), key = lambda x: x[1])
print my_dict[largest]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have no additional information about any relation between elements in any set (like keys in dictionary in that case) then you have to check each element => complexity `O(n)` (linear) - the only improvement can be using some build-in function like `max`

If you need quite often to obtain (or pop) max value then think about different structure (like `heap`).